# Activate action onClick in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following chunk of code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li/>".$row['trendName']."<input type='submit' name='Dispay' value='Display All Items'  onclick='action='http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php';'/>";
    echo"<br />";
}
```

So, this I want to do is for each element on the list to create a button. When I will click at this button I want to hit a URL.

Let's say that we have only one element on the list (`Movies`). By clicking on the button next to the movies, I want to move to another URL: `http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php`
and furthermore to pass to the other URL the name of the element (i.e. `Movies`)

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a ordinary link for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend to use `<button></button>` in html 5 to create a button.

```
echo "<button type='submit' name='Display' onclick='javascript:location=\"http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php?value=$row['trendName']\"'>Display</button>";
```

As suggested above, a link is the proper way to do so.

```
<?php echo "<a href='http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php?value=".$row['trendName']."'>Display</a>"; ?>
```

You can use `$_GET['value'];` to retrieve your data "trendName"

However "action" is used in the `<form></form>` tag

```
<form action='http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='value' value='<?php echo $row['trendName']; ?>' />
<button type='submit'>Display</button>
</form>
```

here you would use `$_POST['value'];` to retrieve your data "trendName"

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="this.location.href='http://blah.co.uk/DisplayData.php?value=' + $row['trendName']"
```

If you tell, where "someValue" should come from, I'll edit this code later.

However, I would recommend using a link instead.

Comment: The value that I need to pass is the $row['trendName']. And come from a db query.

Comment: Edited. However, look at Art Planteur's answer, the ways he shows are better.